# Why is the string set to null in this wc example?

Tags: d, word-count

I was about curious about the D language today, and so I took a look at the website and came across the following wc implementation on the website:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.stream;

int main (string[] args)
{
    int w_total;
    int l_total;
    ulong c_total;
    int[string] dictionary;

    writefln("   lines   words   bytes file");
    foreach (arg; args[1 .. args.length])
    {
        int w_cnt, l_cnt;
        bool inword;

        auto c_cnt = std.file.getSize(arg);
        if (c_cnt < 10_000_000)
        {
            size_t wstart;
            auto input = cast(string)std.file.read(arg);

            foreach (j, c; input)
            {
                if (c == '\n')
                ++l_cnt;
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                {
                }
                else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ||
                    c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                {
                    if (!inword)
                    {
                        wstart = j;
                        inword = true;
                        ++w_cnt;
                    }
                }
                else if (inword)
                {   
                    auto word = input[wstart .. j];

                    dictionary[word]++;
                    inword = false;
                }
            }
            if (inword)
            {   
                auto w = input[wstart .. input.length];
                dictionary[w]++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            auto f = new BufferedFile(arg);
            string buf;

            while (!f.eof())
            {   
                char c;

                f.read(c);
                if (c == '\n')
                ++l_cnt;
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                {
                    if (inword)
                    buf ~= c;
                }
                else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' ||
                    c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                {
                    if (!inword)
                    {
                        buf.length = 0;
                        buf ~= c;
                        inword = 1;
                        ++w_cnt;
                    }
                    else
                        buf ~= c;
                }
                else if (inword)
                {
                    if (++dictionary[buf] == 1)
                        buf = null;
                    inword = 0;
                }
            }
            if (inword)
            {
                dictionary[buf]++;
            }
        }
        writefln("%8s%8s%8s %s\n", l_cnt, w_cnt, c_cnt, arg);
        l_total += l_cnt;
        w_total += w_cnt;
        c_total += c_cnt;
    }

    if (args.length > 2)
    {
        writefln("--------------------------------------\n%8s%8s%8s total",
        l_total, w_total, c_total);
    }

    writefln("--------------------------------------");

    foreach (word1; dictionary.keys.sort)
    {
        writefln("%3s %s", dictionary[word1], word1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Anyway, on line 86, the code sets buf to null when it's the first occurrence of the word in the dictionary.

```
             if (++dictionary[buf] == 1)
                buf = null;
             inword = 0;
            }
```

What is the benefit of doing this?  I tested the method with that part left out, and I get the same results.

Comment: That example is actually very dated. I believe it predates D2 even. I can't see a reason it'd set buf to null. The Associative Array page [has an version](http://dlang.org/hash-map.html) that appears to be more up to date with D coding conventions.

Comment: @eco: You might want to put that in as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here. But, that's pretty old code so the reason probably has to do with immutable. In older versions of D, there was no immutable in the type system, so a string was just an alias for plain char[].

In an associative array, if you change a key it can break it since the hashes don't match up - you could get two entries in the tree where there should be only one and other tough to find bugs (hence in newer D versions, if you try int[char[]], it will complain that the key must be immutable).

Changing length to zero, which the code does for a new word, might reuse the existing buffer. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't now, but maybe it did at the time. This could overwrite an existing entry in the hash table. Setting it to null ensures that there's actually a new buffer allocated.

Bottom line: it probably would randomly not work without that line at the time it was written.